# VLC: How to "continue playback" regardless of how close from start or end I was?

Tags: vlc-media-player

I already have the "Continue playback?" option set to "Always", which usually works great.

But if I stop a video at some position near the start or end, close it, then later play the video again, the video doesn't resume at the last position.

I'm very sure this happens whenever I'm <5% from either the start or end of the video. (E.g. if a video is exactly 100 min or 1:40:00 long, then stopping the video at 5:01 or 1:34:59 will allow me to resume at those points, while stopping the video at 4:59 or 1:35:01 will not allow me to resume.)

How do I force VLC to "continue playback" regardless of how close from start or end I was?

(I'm using version 3.0.20.)

Comment: Are you still using “3.0.18 Vetinari” because I believe VLC is up to version 3.0.20 right now in December 2023.

Comment: If you wish to set-up bookmarks, see these extensions : [Moments' Tracker](https://addons.videolan.org/p/1154020/) and [VLC Permanents Bookmarks](https://addons.videolan.org/p/1718547).

Comment: @Giacomo1968: Yes I'm using 3.0.20 (I tried editing the post but my edit was rejected). // When OP posted in 2022, 3.0.18 was the latest version. // It doesn't matter anyway because the problem exists whether one is using 3.0.18 or 3.0.20.

Comment: @harrymc: No I do not wish to set up bookmarks or use those extensions.

Comment: @harrymc: Answered.

Comment: @user103496 Are you the same person as “user1655234?” If so, you should merge accounts to reclaim your question. More information can be [found here](https://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts).

Comment: vlc --long-help

Answer (score 0):

This seems like this is a VLC bug and merits posting a bug report
on the VLC forums.
See [VLC Report bugs](https://wiki.videolan.org/Report_bugs/).

Bookmarks will work for your purpose, although it's not automatic
and so is not the easiest solution to use.
A couple of good bookmarking extensions are
[Moments' Tracker](https://addons.videolan.org/p/1154020/)
and
[VLC Permanents Bookmarks](https://addons.videolan.org/p/1718547).

Comment: have you tested it or have you found other posts about it to state that it looks like a bug ?

Comment: @1NN: The opposite : I haven't found any reference to such a problem, so it seems like "normal" behavior by VLC. I suppose it's rare for people to stop toward the end of the video and expect to come back to the same spot, so this wasn't noticed or wasn't seen as a problem until now.

Comment: I added this paragraph to the above Q: *I'm very sure this happens whenever I'm <5% from either the start or end of the video. (E.g. if a video is exactly 100 min or 1h 40 min long, then stopping the video at 5:01 or 1:34:59 will allow me to resume at those points, while stopping the video at 4:59 or 1:35:0.1 will not allow me to resume.)* // Given how precise this 5% threshold is, I believe this is a deliberate feature and not a bug.

Comment: If this is an intended "feature", somebody should disable it. It's still worth a bug-report, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

### Update

Last save location for a file is saved in the `vlc-qt-interface.ini` file which on windows is located in `C:\Users\%user%\AppData\Roaming\vlc`. It has a form like:

```
[RecentsMRL] 
list=file:///[some path]
times=106472
```

If the video playing was too close to the beginning or to the end of the file (as much as 20 seconds), the variable will always be `times=0`. So this looks like some programmer's bug in how that variable is saved within the file. I have not found any user adjustable setting which could influence this, even going through the "Show all settings".

So this looks like either a bug or a feature. Given the recent edit of the question, it looks more like a feature.

### Old answer

- Make sure that in `Tools-> Preferences -> Interface` the "save recently played items” is checked
- If that item is already enabled, disable it and close VLC. Reopen VLC and re-enable it.
- If it still doesnt work, open files from  `Media -> Open recent Media`.

Note that for compressed media (mp4, h.265 ecc ) the option will always resume from the closest keyframe. So if your video is closed before the first keyframe, it will resume from the beginning. Also if it was closed after the last keyframe.

Comment: First line: Did you mean "Preferences" instead of "Playback"? // First two bullet points: Yes I've already done this. // Third bullet point: Doesn't work.

Comment: @user103496 yes, sorry for the typo. See my UPDATE to the answer.